# How can replace a string value using one column in another column?

Tags: python-3.x, pyspark

How can replace a string value using one column in another column?

My DataFrame is look like

Fname,MiddleName,Expected_FName

John D Hoye,D,John Hoye

John D Hoye,Null,John D Hoye

John D-Doe Hoye,D-Doe,John Hoye

John D,D,John

D John,D,John

JohnD H,D,JohnD H

John Doe Hoy,Doe Hoy,John

Basically for some cases, the first name contains the value in middle name. I need to create a first name column which should not contain the values in the middle name.
How I can create a column "Expected_FName" in PySpark?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `expr`:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

df = spark.createDataFrame([
    'John D Hoye,D,John Hoye'.split(','),
    ['John D Hoye', None, 'John D Hoye'],
    'John D-Doe Hoye,D-Doe,John Hoye'.split(','),
    'John D,D,John'.split(','),
    'D John,D,John'.split(','),
    'John Doe Hoy,Doe Hoy,John'.split(',')
], 'Fname,MiddleName,Expected_FName'.split(','))

res = df.withColumn('expected', functions.expr("regexp_replace(Fname, MiddleName, '')")
res.show()

+---------------+----------+--------------+----------+
|          Fname|MiddleName|Expected_FName|  expected|
+---------------+----------+--------------+----------+
|    John D Hoye|         D|     John Hoye|John  Hoye|
|    John D Hoye|      null|   John D Hoye|      null|
|John D-Doe Hoye|     D-Doe|     John Hoye|John  Hoye|
|         John D|         D|          John|     John |
|         D John|         D|          John|      John|
|   John Doe Hoy|   Doe Hoy|          John|     John |
+---------------+----------+--------------+----------+
```

Comment: There is one more case where Fname = "John Dick H" and MiddleName = "D" expected result is ="John Dick H". In this case, do not remove "D". How can it do?